# Threshold for multi-class classification

Tags: python, keyword, threshold, multiclass-classification

I'm currently working on a multi-class classification project. In the proposed method, each class is defined by a lexicon list, and each term in the lexicon is defined by a representativeness weight or score, determined from statistical measures (TF-IDF for example).

My question is the following: is there a simple way to determine the appropriate threshold value for each class, based on the weights of the terms in particular, to classify a document ?

All suggestions are welcome.

Thanks for everything!

EDIT :

```py
tf_ = TfidfVectorizer(norm='l2',min_df=0, use_idf=True, smooth_idf=False, sublinear_tf=True, tokenizer=tokenize)
tfidf_matrix = tf_.fit_transform(corpus_theme)

feature_names = tf_.get_feature_names()
sorted_tfidf = {theme: {} for theme in themes_uniq}

for theme in themes_uniq:
    print('\nThème : {0}'.format(theme))
    
    index = theme_match[theme]
    feature_index = tfidf_matrix[index,:].nonzero()[1]
    tfidf_scores = zip(feature_index, [tfidf_matrix[index, x] for x in feature_index])

    res = {}
    
    for w, s in [(feature_names[i], s) for (i, s) in tfidf_scores]:
        res[w] = s

    res = {k: v for k, v in sorted(res.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}
    res = take(5, res.items())
    sorted_tfidf[theme] = {item[0] : item[1] for item in res if item[0] in dictdump['lexicons'][theme].keys()}
    

    for key, pair in enumerate(res):
        print('{0} : {1}'.format(pair[0], str(pair[1])))

--------------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Theme : Environnement
pollution : 0.22100993944113367
biodiversité : 0.21461866899564078
émissions : 0.19949436710171628
pétrole : 0.1509508724016146
giec : 0.14255687423527078

Theme : Sport
championnat : 0.24159536867091702
coupe : 0.20204707419916948
olympiques : 0.1954497772157803
match : 0.1815176328907646
finaliste : 0.17407788073364622

Theme : Politique
scrutin : 0.14487046470551654
législatives : 0.14487046470551654
libéralisme : 0.14217858901989705
candidature : 0.1372912061161422
candidat : 0.1329112819463253

Etc.
```

I thus have for each of my categories (17 in total) a weighted lexicon list. I am now trying to classify my future documents on the basis of this information, but I do not know how to determine a threshold value for each of the classes, which would allow me to say that document 1 belongs to classes 'Environnement' and 'Sport' because it contains such words with such weights.

Comment: Share some starter code, so as to get an idea of what you are trying to design.

Comment: Thanks, I did it :)